# Open XML: We found a problem with some content in 'myfile.xlsx'

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating an Excel file using the Open XML SDK.

```
Worksheet newWs = new Worksheet()
{
    MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "x14ac" }
};
```

When I add a `SheetViews` instance as follows,

```
SheetViews sheetViews = new SheetViews();
SheetView sheetView = new SheetView();
Selection selection = new Selection() { ActiveCell = "B1" };
sheetView.Append(selection);
sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
newWs.Append(sheetViews);
```

I get an error as shown below (and also `ActiveCell` is not working):

> We found a problem with some content in 'myfile.xlsx'. Do you want us
>   to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

Comment: Create a simple workbook *as a user in Excel* with a sheet view such as you're trying to create with the code in the question. Open that in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool and compare the code that generates to create the workbook with what you're using. That should help you track down the problem.

Comment: Which version of the Open XML library are you using?

Comment: @Cindy Meister. this was issue with ordering. I could not post entire code here. but I had applied sheetviews after applying styles. which openxml didn't like. so I get to know about this by using XML SDK productivity tool. so please post an answer I can accept. :)

Comment: For this kind of thing - a basic trouble-shooting set, that I post on 90+% of questions about the Open XML SDK - I shouldn't write an answer. If *you* want to write up what you found (I assume you mean the XML schema requires elements to be inserted in an exact order) that would be meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was issue with ordering of the excel xml elements.

I had applied sheetviews after applying styles.

Which openxml didn't like.

So I get to know about this by using XML SDK productivity tool. Which helped making correct order.